# Even numbers greater than 6 as sum of two specific primes

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

It is well known fact that it is very hard to prove [Goldbach's strong conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldbach%27s_conjecture) but perhaps some weaker variations can be proved ,so my question is:
Is it true that every even number greater than 6 can be represented as the sum of an odd prime number and an [safe prime](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safe_prime)?

Comment: That's actually a stronger variation.

Comment: @anon, yes, but I suppose that means that, if it's false, it would be easier to prove it's false. pedja, care to remind us what a "safe prime" is?

Comment: @anon,Why do you think so?

Comment: pedja: Because Goldbach immediately follows from it, but not vice versa. @Gerry: Good point.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. For example, 32 is not the sum of an odd prime and a safe prime.  This is because the only safe primes smaller than 32 are 5, 7, 11, and 23, and we have:

$\begin{align*}
32&= 5 + 27\\
32&= 7 + 25\\
32&= 11 + 21\\
32&= 23 + 9\end{align*}$

I whipped up [an inefficient perl program](http://pastebin.com/cv3UwkGr) to calculate counterexamples, which include: 32, 56, 92, 98, 122, 128, 140, 152, 176, 194, 212, 224, 242, 254, 260, 272, 296, 302, 308, 326, 332, 368, 392, 398, 410, 422, 434, 452, 458, 476, 488, 500, 512, 518, 524, 536, 542, 560, 572, 596, 602, 632, 644, 656, 662, 674, 686, 692, 704, 710, 728, 752, 770, 782, 788,
800...

Based on [the heuristic justification of Goldbach's conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldbach%27s_conjecture#Heuristic_justification) and the assumption that the primality of odd $k$ and the primality of $\dfrac{k-1}{2}$ are independent, I would conjecture that there are only a finite number of such counterexamples.  The expected number of solutions should be about $\dfrac{n}{2\log(n)^3}$.  The same argument applies even if both primes are safe, giving about $\dfrac{n}{2\log(n)^4}$ solutions.  But the experimental evidence is not very convincing, so I wonder if there is some flaw in this argument?  Also, I'm suspicious of the fact that the program outputs $32$, $128$, $512$, and eventually $2048$ as well.  Is there some reason that if the sum of two odd primes is an odd power of two, neither of them can be safe?

EDIT: André Nicolas has shown in [his answer to my follow-up question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/64387/is-there-any-number-greater-than-8-of-the-form-22k1-which-is-the-sum-of-a-p/64397#64397) that there are an infinite number of exceptions to this claim.

Comment: ,20=13+7, where 7 is safe prime

Comment: Oops!  I'll look for another one...  Found it!  pedja, I'm sorry for being wrong (again).

Comment: The sequence $32,56,92\dots$ isn't in the OEIS. Maybe you or somebody else might want to submit it... :)

Comment: Dan, sorry for the editing inconvenience, race conditions I suppose...

Comment: J. M., I submitted it and it is under review. https://oeis.org/A195324