# Is there any number greater than 8 of the form $2^{2k+1}$ which is the sum of a prime and a safe prime?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Is there any number greater than 8 of the form $2^{2k+1}$ which is the sum of a prime and a [safe prime](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safe_prime)?  While [answering @pedja's question about the existence of any such representations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/64109/even-numbers-greater-than-6-as-sum-of-two-specific-primes/64111#64111) I was surprised to discover that $32$, $128$, $512$, and $2048$ cannot be represented in this way, and I've since [found](http://pastebin.com/ZP8kN4iB) that the same is true for $8192$, $32768$, $131072$, $524288$, $2097152$, and $8388608$.  Is there any counterexample?  If not, how can it be proved?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From Nicolas's argument I realized that it was sufficient to check if $2^{2n+1}-7$ was prime. A much easier task than the usual brute forcing. After a few minutes of manual testing on wolfram alpha I found that $2^{39}$ could indeed be written as the sum of a prime and a safeprime:

$$7+549755813881=549755813888=2^{39}.$$

Edit: I wrote a sage program to check all of the odd powers of two less than 2000. It seems I was a bit lucky since the next examples are 715 and 1983. I checked OEIS and numbers such that $2^{n}-7$ are prime has its own [page](http://oeis.org/A059609).

Comment: Wow! ........... (39 of these)

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=factor+2%5E39-7

Answer (score 12):

The congruential argument below shows that we need only worry about the safe prime $7$.

An odd power of $2$ is congruent to $-1$ modulo $3$.  Let $p$ be a safe prime.  Then, except in the cases $p=5$ and $p=7$, $p$ is of the form $2(6k\pm 1)+1$.  But $p$ cannot be of the form $2(6k+1)+1$, so it is of the form $2(6k-1)+1$, that is, $p$ is congruent to $-1$ modulo $3$.  The safe prime $5$ is also congruent to $-1$ modulo $3$.  (The only safe prime that escapes this congruential net is $7$.)

So if $2^{2n+1}=p+q$, where $p$ is a safe prime other than $7$, then $q$ must be divisible by $3$. In particular, if $q$ is prime, $q$ must be $3$.

But this is not possible, since (apart from the case $p=5$) a safe prime $p$ is congruent to $3$ modulo $4$, and hence $p+3$ is congruent to $2$ modulo $4$. The case $p=5$ accounts for the decomposition $8=5+3$.

Thus if $2^{2n+1}=p+q$, where $p$ and $q$ are primes and $p$ is safe, we must have $p=7$.  So the only question that remains is to look for primes $q$ of the form $q=2^{2n+1}-7$.

There likely is some literature on primes of the form $2^{2n+1}-7$. A feeble attempt at experimentation did not locate any, but there is certainly not always a simple small divisor.

Comment: I have: $2^{2k+1} = q + r$, $r = 2p+1$, $4^k = p + (q+1)/2$.  What am I missing?

Comment: Ahh, got it.  Now I wonder if there are any other classes of exceptions that invalidate the heuristic argument I suggested in my answer to the other question?

Comment: But I guess it is still possible that $2^{2k+1} = 7+q$ for some prime $q$?  This is a great answer but I've unaccepted it for the moment.

Comment: @Dan Brumleve: No problem, easy come easy go. It is not often that simple congruential conditions get us this far. Yes, $7$ is the only possible exception.  The weird safe primes are $5$ and $7$, and $5$ was no trouble.

Comment: André, I am curious how did you think of mod 3?  Was it because of the odd exponent of 2 or the fact that there are 3 undetermined variables?

Comment: @Dan Brumleve: A little mulling over numbers showed that the difference between $2^{2n+1}$ and a safe prime is usually divisible by $3$. Paid no attention to $7$ since it is obviously special. So had to rule out a difference of $3$ (easy) and $7$ (not easy, indeed as it turns out not possible).